# How to match string value by regular expression?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am making application which depend on html.i pass the html file in code and all data are display in console but my problem is that how to match string by using regular expression i am not giving all data of html is to large 
this is value which is print on console

```
www.ryanair.com" title="Home">Home</a> | <a href="http://www.ryanair.com/site/EN/faqs.php" title="F.A.Q." target="_blank">F.A.Q.</a> | <a href="http://www.ryanair.com/site/EN/conditions.php?view=privacy" title="Privacy Policy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="http://www.ryanair.com/site/EN/conditions.php" title="General Terms &amp; Conditions of Carriage" target="_blank">General Terms &amp; Conditions of Carriage</a> | <a href="http://www.ryanair.com/en/terms-and-conditions/copywrite" title="Terms of Use" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="http://www.ryanair.com/site/EN/faqs.php?sect=CONTACT&amp;div=int_sup" title="Contact Us" target="_blank">Contact Us</a> | <a href="javascript:infoWin('trvfee',0,0,'EN');" title="Fees">Fees</a></div><div id="copyr">Copyright 2009 Ryanair Ltd.</div><input type="hidden" id="language" value=""><input type="hidden" id="culture" value=""><script type="text/javascript"> xtnv=document; xtsd=(window.location.protocol.indexOf('https:')==0?'https://logs152':'http://logc158'); xtsite=(window.location.hostname.indexOf('www.bookryanair.com')!=-1)?'384235':'385193'; xtn2="3"; xtpage="BookingProcess_IE::Search"; xtdi="1";  </script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/Ryanair/xtcore.js"></script><noscript><img width="1" height="1" alt="" src="http://logc158.xiti.com/hit.xiti?s=384235&amp;s2=3&amp;p=BookingProcess_IE::Search&amp;di=1"></noscript></div></div></div><div class="clr"></div><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
                    var MacsArray = new Array();

                var SortedStations = new Array(
            "AAR","ABZ","AGA","AHO","ALC","LEI","AOI","BCN","BRI","EGC","SXF","BZR","BIQ","BLL","BHX","BLQ","BOD","BOH","BTS","BRE","BES","BDS","BRS","BSL","BRQ","CRL","BZG","CAG","CCF","CND","ORK","CUF","LDY","DNR","DSA","DUB","MME","NRN","EMA","EDI","EIN","FAO","FEZ","FSC","HHN","FUE","GDN","GOA","GRO","PIK","GSE","GRX","LPA","GRZ","GNB","LBC","HAU","IBZ","XRY","FKB","KTW","KUN","KIR","KLU","NOC","KGS","KRK","SUF","ACE","LPP","LCA","LRH","LBA","LIL","LIG","LNZ","LPL","LCJ","LGW","LTN","STN","LDE","MST","MAD","AGP","MLA","MAN","RAK","MRS","FMM","BGY","MPL","MJV","NDR","NTE","NCL","NQY","FNI","OSI","RYG","TRF","OUD","PMO","PMI","BVA","MMX","XCR","PMF","PGF","PEG","PSR","PSA","PDV","PIS","OPO","POZ","PRG","PUY","REU","RHO","RIX","RMI","RDZ","CIA","RZE","SZG","SDR","SCQ","SVQ","SNN","VXO","EBU","NYO","VST","SZZ","TMP","TNG","TFS","TLN","TUF","TPS","TRS","TRN","VLC","VLL","TSF","VRN","VOL","WRO","ZAD","ZAZ","RLG","KSD","CSO","SFT","TLL","HUY","RJK","SKG","VCE","VNO","CHQ","CFU","LEJ"
                );

                var Stations = new Array();
                Stations["AAR"] = new Station("AAR", "", "Aarhus", true, true, new Array("AGP","RYG","STN"));
Stations["AGP"] = new Station("AGP", "", "Malaga", true, true, new Array("AAR","BCN","BGY","BHX","BLL","BLQ","BOH","BRE","BRS","BTS","BVA","CRL","CSO","DUB","EDI","EIN","EMA","FMM","GSE","HAU","HHN","IBZ","KRK","LBA","LPL","MAN","MMX","MRS","MST","NRN","NYO","ORK","PIK","PSA","RYG","SCQ","SDR","SNN","STN","SXF","TMP","TRF","VCE","VLC","VLL","VST","WRO","ZAZ"));
Stations["RYG"] = new Station("RYG", "", "Oslo (Rygge)", true, true, new Array("AAR","AGP","ALC","BCN","BVA","BZR","CIA","CRL","DUB","FAO","FMM","GDN","HHN","KGS","KRK","KUN","LGW","LPL","LRH","MAD","MAN","NCL","NYO","PMI","PMO","POZ","RIX","SKG","STN","SXF","TLL","TMP","VCE","VLC","WRO","XCR","ZAD"));


i done this for match all string value in code
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {  
    [self sendRequest ];
    //Extraction of valid mail ids
    //NSString * searchString = @" para.g@gmail.com sourabh_84368@gmail.com abc@def.in abcd@yahoomail.com mobisoft@mail.in andy@rediffmail.com";
    NSString * searchString = loginstatus;
    NSString *regexString = @"[a-z0-9_.%]+@[a-z0-9_.%]+\\.[a-z][a-z][a-z]";
    //NSString *regexString = @"Stations\["(.*)"\] = new Station\((.*)\);";
    NSArray  *matchArray   = nil;
    matchArray = [searchString componentsMatchedByRegex:regexString];
    NSLog(@"matchArray: %@", matchArray);
    // Override point for customization after application launch
    //NSString* source = @"Test;12;Y";
//  NSArray* columns = [source componentsSeparatedByRegex:@";\\s*"];
//  NSLog([columns description]);
//    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

pleas some one help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSPredicate` to match string against a regular expression.

```
NSString *searchString = @"loginStatus";
NSString *regexString = @"[a-z0-9_.%]+@[a-z0-9_.%]+\\.[a-z][a-z][a-z]";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self matches %@", regexString];
BOOL isStringValid = [predicate evaluateWithObject:searchString];
```

Comment: i get the whole html page by passing nsurlconnection like this NSURLRequest *theRequest; print the data -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{      
 loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
 NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus);  
 
         
 [connection release];  
  
} 
which i print html page in loginstatus i want fire regular expression for serach string it this possible

Comment: I think you have to write the html into string format .And than fire the Regular expression for what ever the string you want search .I hope so.I just have idea I think @empty Stack may help you

Comment: Regexs within `NSPredicate`s must match the entire string. Add `.*` to the start and end of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are developing for iOS4+, use the [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class
- If you need to target previous iOS releases:

  - you may try using `NSPredicate`, which supports ICU RegEx syntax thru the [`MATCHES`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868) operator. But it only allows you to test if the string match, and can't do replacements nor extract matching strings, so this is quite limited.
  - You can use Third-Party libraries like [`RegExKit`](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: i get the whole html page by passing nsurlconnection like this NSURLRequest *theRequest; print the data -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection { loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus); [connection release]; } which i print html page in loginstatus i want fire regular expression for serach string it this possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use regular expressions to parse the HTML you may be going about it the wrong way. There are dedicated parsers already for this, such as NSXMLParser which will be easier for you to use in your app than re-inventing the wheel writing Regular expressions to get data out of HTML.

Comment: Except if the HTML is not proper XHTML -- which is unfortunately quite common -- making the HTML DOM content invalid regarding XML parsing (e.g. a `<br>` tag in the HTML instead of `<br/>`, etc). In such case, HTML parsing can't be performed using an XML parser.

Comment: @Abizem Nice answer until implementation time when badly formatted html is the target.  Or the file size is 2.5MB and the DOM is 8MB.  It may be all I want is the unload URL or the META REFRESH path.  The XPath syntax is convoluted and writing the delegates for NSXMLParser is substantial.  I have used NSXMLParser when I want the entire contents and also use REs when I want a small part.

Comment: I agree that `NSXMLParser` is better than regex, but some times `NSXMLParser` doesn't cut it (due to malformed HTML). My order of preference for parsing HTML is:
1. `NSXMLParser`
2. libxml
3. Javascript in a `UIWebView` using the `evaluateJavascript:` method to pass the data
4. 'Role your own' parsing with string methods.